# get result where input has more char than in database

Tags: mysql

this is an example of my table

```
code    | name     | class
R100    | adm      | VIP
R101    | adm      | VVIP
R101    | adm      | 1
R200    | act      | VIP
R201    | act      | VVIP
R202    | act      | 1
```

and I have an input like this: `name='a' and class='VIP B'` some other input will be `class='1A'` or `class='2ISO'` or `class='2NC'` how can I deal with this problem?

at first I'm using `where class like '$class%'` when I realize I'm not a smart man...

Comment: So you want to return rows whose class is the same as the beginning of the input class?

Comment: @Barmar basically, yeah. So far that's the problem I face

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use: `WHERE '$class' LIKE CONCAT(class, '%')`

Or: `WHERE class = LEFT('$class', CHAR_LENGTH(class))`

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b9bd/4)

Comment: Oh! So you flip the position where input comes first. I never thought that, thanks

Comment: wait, why is this only work for VVIP? I tried with another input like VIP A or 2ISO but there's no result?

Comment: It works for me, see my sqlfiddle demo

Comment: I just realize, in my db it's not 'vip' but 'vip  ' and '1    ' not '1', at first I thought all of them has 5 char, but I also find '3' in there, with this, how can I do it?

Comment: Add a space to the end of `$class`

Comment: I never thought it was that simple, thanks

Comment: I found better solution `'$class' LIKE CONCAT(REPLACE(class,' ', ''),'%')` do you think it works? I tried it and so far it works every time.